# I want formula for compund interest with regular and fixed replenishments

Tags: interest-rate

For example:

Let's suppose that at the end of the first year I got \$8 000  of revenue (like I have a business or something). I put the money in a bank at the beginning of the second year, annual percentage rate was 10% (from now on I assume that the annual percentage rate will remain the same). At the end of the second year there were \$8 800 on my bank account, but I added \$8 000 to it at the beginning of the third year, thus at the end at the end of the third year I had \$18480 on my bank account, instead of \$9680. I continue to replenish my bank account every year by \$8 000 (inflation is ignored), until the beginning of year number N, when I will do it for the last time. I want to know what sum of money I will have at the end of year number N.

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from calculating the sum of this geometric sequence?

Comment: This seems like it is off-topic. Perhaps you can try posting it on the Personal Finance SE, but I would recommend just crunching numbers in Excel, Google Docs or Open Office.

Comment: This isn't related to personal finances, I came up with it when I were trying to solve a problem from my microeconomic textbook. And I would prefer either formula or algorithm over "blackbox" function of spreedsheet program. "What exactly is stopping you from calculating the sum of this geometric sequence?" I have no idea how to derrive it. Could you please give me the formula for this sum of geometric sequences, if you already know?

Comment: [Sure](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=sum+of+geometric+sequences)!

Comment: Hmm... After looking close, I don't see how it's helpful because I don't see how it accounts for regular replenishments of bank account from my side (no pun intended).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not concern the discipline of economics.

Comment: This formula can help to decide if something is a good investment. Like  "Should I buy this machine that yields $8 000 each year, considering that I can put the revenue in the bank and periodically add money to my bank account?"

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the future value of an annuity. If you have a payment P paid for N years, compounding at an interest rate i, the future value of that is:

$FV=P*( (1+i)^N - 1)/i$

This will give you the future value at the beginning of the year. To get it for the end you multiply with (1+i). In your example filling in P=8000, i=10%, and N=2 gives you 16800, which when multiplied with 1.1 gives you the desired 18480.

Comment: how did you derrive this formula?

Comment: I tried your formula with my example. Doesn't seem to work. Please show me how to correctly use it to get  $18480 given situation in my example.

Comment: The formula gives you the beginning of the year sum. Multiply with (1+i) to get the end of year sum. I have edited my answer.